# How to use multiple Mongodb in flask

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongodb-query, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two mysql database one is localhost and another is in server now, am going to create simple app in python using flask for that application i would like to connect the both mysql DB (local and server).

Any one please suggest how to connect multiple DB into flask.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
client = MongoClient()
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.sampleDB1
```

Sample code if possible.

Thanks

Comment: It's better to create a config file and specify your Mongodb connection properties then run your application with one of those config's.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, finally figured it out.

Instead of using

```
client = MongoClient()
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.sampleDB1
```

Delete all that and try this:

```
mongo1 = PyMongo(app, uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/Database1')
mongo2 = PyMongo(app, uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/Database2')
```

Then, when you want to call a particular database you can use:

```
@app.route('/routenamedb1', methods=['GET'])
def get_data_from_Database1():

Database1 = mongo1.db.CollectionName ##Notice I use mongo1,
#If I wanted to access database2 I would use mongo2

#Walk through the Database for DC to
for s in Database1.find():
#Modifying code
return data
```

Answer (score 0):

create model.py and separate instances of 2 databases inside it, then in app.py:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MODEL'] = model.my1st_database()
app.config['MODEL2'] = model.my2nd_database()
```

works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#This technique can be used to connect to multiple databases or database servers:
app = Flask(__name__)

# connect to MongoDB with the defaults
mongo1 = PyMongo(app)

# connect to another MongoDB database on the same host
app.config['MONGO2_DBNAME'] = 'dbname_two'
mongo2 = PyMongo(app, config_prefix='MONGO2')

# connect to another MongoDB server altogether
app.config['MONGO3_HOST'] = 'another.host.example.com'
app.config['MONGO3_PORT'] = 27017
app.config['MONGO3_DBNAME'] = 'dbname_three'
mongo3 = PyMongo(app, config_prefix='MONGO3')
```

Comment: Got `pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: Unknown option config_prefix`

Comment: From source code: `Flask-PyMongo no longer accepts many of the configuration variables it did in previous versions. You must now use a MongoDB URI to configure Flask-PyMongo`